# google action script (Spreadsheet) clear(options) method of Range class not working as expected

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Pulling data from a spreadsheet to display via Google visualization however the date-time objects are raising an error:"The script completed but the returned value is not a supported return type" is generated.

I found that after a manual conversion of the date-time to "plain text" format, everything worked fine.

The Range class has a clear method that should be able to remove formatting but it is instead clearing the contents from the cells.

```
clear({formatOnly:true})
```

Snippet:

```
  var sheetId = '1k1p0SNweftGVBIH4vxBFlkAYEhdRrepmboSyQnm_OXc_we'; 
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(sheetId).getSheets()[3];

  //The timestamp object causes an error when imported in G.A.S. so the next 4 lines of code removes the formatting.

  var range = sheet.getRange("A1:A999"); 
  range.clear({formatOnly:true}); // remove formatting for column A
  range = sheet.getRange("E1:E999");
  range.clear({formatOnly:true}); // remove formatting for column E

  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
```

Can anyone please help to clarify this and assist with a solution?

Answer (score 2):

`.clearFormat()` or `.clear({formatOnly:true})` clears text formatting for the cell or cells in the range, but does not reset any number formatting rules.

```
var range = sheet.getRange("A1:A");
range.clearFormat();
```

If you want to set plain text format,

```
var range = sheet.getRange("A1:A");
range.setNumberFormat('@STRING@');
```

You can further refer [range class documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#clearformat).

Comment: iJay thanks. It works like a charm! 
can you point me to some further reading on formatting?

Comment: Added a link for your reference, So you can mark it as an answer. :) Thanks